# Upload PDF using ajax and form keeps failing

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have this code that keeps failing do do its job. I'm trying to pass file data ass well as ID to the php side, but it keeps failing. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Please help.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#form_upload').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: 'updateFile.php',
      type: 'post',
      contentType:false,
      cache: false,
      processData:false,
      data: {docID: document.getElementById('txt_docID').value, formUpload: new FormData($('#form_upload'))},
      success: function(data){
      alert(data);  
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});

<div id="divItemSelector" >
<form id = 'form_upload' class 'uploadform' action="updateFile.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="fileUpload" id="fileUpload" >
  <input id='txt_docID' type="text" name="txt_docID" style="visibility:hidden">
  <input type="button" value="Close" name="btn_close" onclick = "hideDiv()" style="float: right;">
  <input type="submit" value="Upload PDF" name="submit" style="float: right;">
</form>
```

and on php side im trying to use

```
$_POST['docID']
```

and

```
$_FILES["fileUpload"]["name"]
```

to get to my data.

Answer (score 0):

in your code `type: 'post'` should be `method: 'post'`